# CVS: Tracking all the changes in a branch

Tags: version-control, cvs

Say, I have three branches, Branch b0, b1 and b2.
b1 is forked some years back from b0 and b2 recently from b1.

All changes done on branch b2 are done by me and another developer, now what I need to do is to merge all my changes to branch b0.

I see two ways of doing it:

1. Manually copy-paste code (as code additions are quite independent) or
2. Create a diff file of Current state of branch b2 to the state where b2 was forked from b1. Apply the patch to b0, and manually handle conflicts.

2nd way seems more feasible to me, the only problem I have is how do I create a diff of all changes done on a branch?

Any other better way of doing this are also welcome.

Thanks,